# blackjack dealer hand generator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, random, playing-cards

I wrote a piece of blackjack code - for dealer dealing cards to himself (python). My question is how can I make it more efficient, faster and neater. I ran it for 1.000.000 iterations and it took 14.7 second which is quite slow, I believe.

```
import random
deck = 4 * [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11]
random.shuffle(deck)


dealer_hand = []
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
hit_on_soft_17 = True
exit = False

while not exit:
    if sum(dealer_hand) == 17 and hit_on_soft_17:
        exit = True
        for i, card in enumerate(dealer_hand):
            if card == 11:
                exit = False
                dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
                break
    if sum(dealer_hand) < 17:
        exit = False
        dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
    if sum(dealer_hand) > 21: 
        exit = True
        for i, card in enumerate(dealer_hand):
            if card == 11:
                exit = False
                dealer_hand[i] = 1
                break
    if sum(dealer_hand) < 22 and sum(dealer_hand) > 17:
        exit = True

print(dealer_hand)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/279748/revisions#rev-body-cd23fdf5-4529-47a0-a38f-d061fdf66f8d) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Why would a dealer need to run this a million times? Things don't need to be faster than necessary for your use case. Popping the back of a list is faster than the front, although the gains may be negligible for such a tiny list. You're also summing the hand unnecessarily many times. You can store that in a variable. Again, sort of a micro optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Testing

One million `print(dealer_hand)` statements executed in 14.7 seconds would be amazing.  I'm running it as I write this answer and it has yet to finish.  Please be clear on exactly what you are timing.

## pop

`deck.pop(0)` is inefficient, since every element in the list must be copied to a new position.  Consider instead using `deck.pop()` to remove a card from the other end of the `deck`.  Alternately, you could use a `deque`, which allows O(1) insertion/removal from either end.  Finally, you could create an iterator (`it = iter(deck)`) and use it to deal cards (`next(it)`); it doesn't actually remove the cards from `deck`, but iterates through them one-by-one.

## sum

If the dealer holds `[10, 8]`, then `sum(dealer_hand)` is computed 5 times in the loop!  Each time, the same value is returned.  You could compute this once at the top of the loop, `dealer_total = sum(dealer_hand)`, and use that variable in subsequent tests.

## Chained conditionals

`if sum(dealer_hand) < 22 and sum(dealer_hand) > 17:` could be written more succinctly and more efficiently as `if 17 < sum(dealer_hand) < 22:`  Of course, `if 17 < dealer_total < 22:` is better still.

## Reserved identifiers

`exit()` is a function ... or it was until you redefined it as a variable.  Use a different identifier, like `done`, instead.

## Bug

If `hit_on_soft_17 = False`, then once the dealer holds `[10, 7]` (or equivalent), none of the `if` conditions will be true, `exit` will remain `False`, and the loop will never end.

## PEP-0008

- `hit_on_soft_17` is a global constant, and should be named in `UPPER_CASE` like `HIT_ON_SOFT_17`.
- Commas should be followed by 1 space

## Use functions

You should always organize your code into functions.